# why does not the alert show up when i call the function?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Can anybody help me understand why this alert won't show up? In the function `newuser()` an alert is supposed to show up, with some text, but nothing happens when I call it. How can I fix this?

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert("cant create that object hos");
    }

    function newuser() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 0 || xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
            name = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value);
            company = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("company").value);
            nationalities = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("nationality").value);
            phonenumber = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("phonenumber").value);
            alert(name, company, nationalities, phonenumber);
        } else {
            setTimeout('newuser()', 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there is an error .. Check your console for more info !!

Comment: first, your function `newuser()` is inside your function `createXmlHttpRequestObject()`. Is it ok?

Comment: what browser are you testing with? With all modern browsers you should be able to see the error console by hitting F12. (also which browser versions do you need to support? if you can avoid supporting IE6, then you can drop that whole silly ActiveX bit)

Comment: @Dorian_gd: absolutely not, the `setTimeout` is in the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
setTimeout(newuser, 1000);
```

Notice: no quotes, and no `()` after the function name.

When you give a string to `setTimeout()`, the expression is evaluated in the global scope. But your function is local to the `createXmlHttpRequestObject()` function, so it's not available in the global scope. You need to reference it by name, not as a string to evaluate.

Also, to get things going, you need to call `newuser()` once at the end of the `createXmlHttpRequestObject()` function.

Using a timeout is a  strange way to do this, though. The usual way is with:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = newuser;
```